# Asynchronous Wt::Http::Client response and request matching

Tags: c++, http, asynchronous, client, wt

I'm new to *Wt3*(version 3.3.9 - because wole project is using it). I've met a problem and now looking for a solution.

I want to make a multithread *Wt::Http::Client*. From documentation I've got that using *Wt::WIOService* with setted thread count can do neaded, but I faced with **problem of recognition which request matched to handled response**.

### Multithreading using Wt::WIOService.

```
  Wt::WIOService io_service;
  io_service.setThreadCount(10);
  io_service.start();
  //
  MyClass my_http_client(io_service);
  my_http_client.Work();
  //
  io_service.stop();
```

In Work() there is a loop that reading a queue of requests and sends them.

### For single thread i was using next piece of code:

In class constructor extended from *Wt::Http::Client*:

```
  done().connect(boost::bind(&MyClass::HandleHttpResponse, this, _1, _2));
```

Handle method:

```
void MyClass::HandleHttpResponse(boost::system::error_code err, const Wt::Http::Message response) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
  // response to inner format
  // then all data goes to another class.
}
```

But when I'm using multithread **I need exactly match request with response**. I can be wrong in understaning Wt [documentation](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/wt3/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1Http_1_1Client.html).
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Question still unresolved, so I moved to [Casablanca lib](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended use of `Wt::Http::Client` is to create a new instance for each request.